# Can I use wildcard operator within Excel Data Connection Properties

Tags: excel

I have a giant accounting spreadsheet and I am looking to sum all revenue accounts using the Excel Data Connection Properties amongst other things. However, I am getting a popup saying my query isn't supported in and I've isolated the issue to the wildcard statement.

```
SELECT AccountDesc, sum(Amount) Total
FROM Department
WHERE AccountDesc like 'Rev%' 
Group by AccountDesc
```

Thank you for all the help in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try change '%' per '*' , in excel normaly '*' works fine.

Comment: Hello Lucas, it doesn't work. I've tried $, ^ as well, and using double-quotes. :/